# Using NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft to update a progress indicator for NSSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: swift, macos

I'm new to `Swift` and `OS X` programming.  I'm trying to use a progress monitor to indicate the progress of my speech synthesizer speaking text.

```
let speechSynthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
speechSynthesizer.delegate = self;
speechSynthesizer.startSpeakingString(contents)
```

I would like to set

```
progressIndicator.maxValue = Double(NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft.characters.count)
```

and then periodically update the progressIndicator with [NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsspeechstatusnumberofcharactersleft), which according to Apple's documentation should hit 0.

Every way I try to access this key, it returns the same inaccurate number, so I'm obviously not using it correctly.  The only example I found was in `Objective-C`

```
NSNumber *n = [[self.speechSynth objectForProperty:NSSpeechStatusProperty error:NULL] objectForKey:NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft];
```

and I tried to translate that to `Swift`, but still, no dice.

```
let count = try speechSynthesizer.objectForProperty(NSSpeechStatusProperty).objectForKey(NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft)
```

I've also tried

```
speechSynthesizer.valueForKey(NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft))
speechSynthesizer.valueWithName(NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft, inPropertyWithKey: NSSpeechStatusProperty))
```

which throw runtime exceptions.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, so things are a bit weirder now.  This key NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft returns the correct value once, but only after I've rebooted my computer.  (Don't ask me how I noticed that :P)  And it's through accessing it this way:     let count = try speechSynthesizer.objectForProperty(NSSpeechStatusProperty).objectForKey(NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft)
I've

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is pretty close to correct:

```
let count = try speechSynthesizer.objectForProperty(NSSpeechStatusProperty).objectForKey(NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft)
```

Without an error message (and since I don't have a Swift 2 compiler handy) I'm guessing the reason that this fails is that the return value of `objectForProperty` isn't known to be an dictionary, so you can't look up values in it.

Here's my quick & dirty Swift 3 playground for testing this:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Cocoa

let synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
synth.startSpeaking("I'm not standing still, I am lying in wait")

// quick way to test for progress without setting up an app and delegate
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
    let statusDict = try! synth.object(forProperty: NSSpeechStatusProperty) as! [String: Any]
    print(statusDict[NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft])
}
```

(Obviously, you don't need all the timer stuff or playground business if you're running this in an app with a synthesizer delegate.)

The key bit (no pun intended) is to cast the return value of `objectForProperty` so that Swift knows it's a dictionary, then look up the number of characters in that dictionary.

Now, this code runs correctly, but it doesn't completely work for setting a progress bar — when the synthesizer finishes speaking, `NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft` is likely to be some nonzero value. (In that case, another status key, `NSSpeechStatusOutputBusy` will become `false`.) So your progress bar will get to not quite 100%, and you can use either the `NSSpeechStatusOutputBusy` key or the delegate `didFinishSpeaking` callback to take your bar the rest of the way, remove your progress UI, or whatever.

Comment: Swift 2.2 didn't quite like that call so I modified it to: let statusDict = try! speechSynthesizer.objectForProperty(NSSpeechStatusProperty) as! [String: Any]
                print(statusDict[NSSpeechStatusNumberOfCharactersLeft])  but it's throwing an exception at runtime.

Comment: For Swift 2.x you probably need `[String: AnyObject]`, not `[String: Any]`.

Comment: Tried that, no luck.  Then updated xcode, tried it with Swift 2.3, then 3.  No luck.  Then I tried your code in a 3 Playground, it won't run, it just sits there trying "Running Playground" forever.  Maybe there's a problem with my dev env :(